Filter the option selection of dynamic dropdown in reactive form
I have a form and a provision to add the field groups dynamically, initially it shows one field group and Add or X it will add and remove the groups
The form itself contains a dropdown and the scenario I'm currently stuck is at, when I select or deselect the options if should reflect in the sibling dropdowns that got added and also when removed .. The selected option should no more be available for other dropdowns and when removed or changed it should be available again...
I'm keeping a track of selected options with index as:
selectedCities = {}; and onChange of dropdown
modifySelectedCities(val, i) { this.selectedCities[i] = val.value; }
The issue I' currently facing is the dropdown when selected with the option itself would be gone since it is no more in the options, below is the code I tried so far
availableCities(i) {
    console.log('sc', this.selectedCities);
    const av = this.cities
      .map((city) => {
        if (!Object.values(this.selectedCities).includes(city)) {
          return city;
        } else {
          null;
        }
      })
      .filter(Boolean);
    console.log('av', av);
    return av;
  }


<div class="card flex justify-content-center">
  <form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <div formArrayName="fieldsArray" class="form-group-container">
      <div
        *ngFor="let fieldGroup of fieldsArray.controls; let i=index"
        [formGroupName]="i"
        class="form-group-city"
      >
        <p-dropdown
          placeholder="Select city"
          formControlName="city"
          [options]="availableCities()"
          (onChange)="modifySelectedCities($event, i); availableCities(i)"
        >
          <ng-template let-option pTemplate="item">
            <div>{{ option }}</div>
          </ng-template>
        </p-dropdown>
        <i
          class="pi pi-times"
          (click)="removeFields(i)"
          style="font-size: 1.5rem; cursor: pointer; margin-left: 10px"
        ></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top: 20px">
      <button pButton type="button" label="Add" (click)="addFields()"></button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

I couldn't think of how to get this work, and I hope it is clear on what I'm trying
Attaching the full repro in this Stackblitz link, any help is highly appreciated, Thank you

I forked your STACKBLITZ, see it this is what you wanted: https://stackblitz.com/edit/cz4u7t-tp74qd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdemo%2Fdropdown-reactive-forms-demo.ts

woah.. exactly @Andriy... Thanks a ton, also thanks for the hint to disable the button until the user selects an option (really makes sense).... please add it as an answer with some explanation (trying hard to understand ) for the future references , it also deserves some appreciation mate

I created forked STACKBLITZ with possible solution.
Some points:

do not use function for the options property, because it will be called on each change detection cycle, rather update it when needed (initial state, add group, remove group)
manage a dictionary of available cities, use it for new groups and update it when needed (initial state, add group, remove group)
add disabled state for the button, so it will be disabled when there no available cities or when user has empty dropdown (did not select any city yet)

I added recalculate function:
recalculateOptions() {
  this.options.forEach((_, ind) => {
    this.options[ind] = [
      ...Object.keys(this.availableCities),
      ...(this.selectedCities[ind] ? [this.selectedCities[ind]] : []),
    ].sort();
  });
  this.addDisabled =
    !Object.keys(this.availableCities).length ||
    this.fieldsArray.length !== this.selectedCities.length;
}


Thank you again  .... noted the point 1, was surprised to see hell lot of logs in console and I was not totally sure why that would happen for an onChange in general (which makes sense with that point you mentioned)

Hey @Andriy, any suggestions if the select here is a multiselect  ... scratching my head for turning the array values when multiple='true' for the strings in the above example

Prime NG dropdown does not support multi select, you should probably use Prime ng Multiselect (https://primeng.org/multiselect)

yes mate, I modified it to multi select and somehow got it working  ...
